# How to deploy a Apache Camel Spring boot project in servicemix?

Tags: spring, maven, apache-camel, apache-servicemix

I have a Spring Boot Apache Camel project. And now I wanted to deploy the same in servicemix. Can some one help me with the steps in deployment of the package which is generated as part of mvn goal.

From Camel examples I was able to get the answer. And the following is the example which helped me:

https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples/camel-example-osgi

But, the problem with this approach would be I will be need to publish my code to maven repository and installation will be happening from there. And the machine in which I run service mix does not have maven(we are not supposed to install maven)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can deploy features or bundles from the file system using the file:// protocol as shown in this documentation: [Servicemix provisioning](http://servicemix.apache.org/docs/6.x/users-guide/provisioning.html)

"Deploy bundles from file system without using Maven:

As we can use file:// as protocol handler to deploy bundles, you can use the following syntax to deploy bundles when they are 
located in a directory which is not available using Maven"

```
<features xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.0.0">
   <feature name="spring-web" version="2.5.6.SEC01">
      <bundle>file:base/bundles/spring-web-2.5.6.SEC01.jar</bundle>
   </feature>
</features>
```